# add field with date field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have created new field in databse for my content type "Flag", its list type field

possible values of it is

```
-Draft 
-Sent 
-Approved 
-Rejected
```

now for this field new table is created,now i want to store date here,what i exactly want is like:

```
-Draft on date DD/MM/YYYY (the date of the creation of the project)
-Sent on date DD/MM/YYYY
-Approved on date DD/MM/YYYY
-Rejected on date DD/MM/YYYY
```

now how to achieve it.

**am using drupal 7**

**how to add date field in this table?**

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114774/add-field-with-date-field/114775

Comment: Have you tried the date module?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the module:

https://drupal.org/project/date

After enabling it you have to add a new field to your Flag content type and choose the Date field type. You can configure the format settings and other options.

Comment: Flag is not content type its field